# Orbits under small perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $l_2$ and $x\in l_2$ is a vector such that the orbit $(T^{n}x)$ is linearly independent.

Can one find an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $||y-x||<\epsilon$ the orbit $(T^{n}y)$ is also linearly independent?

I suspect this is not true in general. Does then a weaker requirement hold: that for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $y\in l_2$ with $||y-x||<\epsilon$ and the orbit $(T^{n}x)$ is linearly independent?